# Pyspark - How do I Flatten Nested Struct Column perserving parent name

Tags: pyspark

If I have a dataframe with a struct column named **structA**, and in it we have 3 columns named **a,b and c**

if I want to flat the struct I can easily do that with **df.select("structA.*")** and it will display

| a | b | c |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 3 |
| 3 | 5 | 6 |

What I wanted is

| structA.a | structA.b | structA.c |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 3 |
| 3 | 5 | 6 |

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid it's not straightforward as it should. You'll need to loop through the schema to get and build your desired column names, then rename columns in a bulk. Something like this

###### Sample dataset

```py
df = spark.createDataFrame([
    ((1, 2, 3),),
    ((4, 5, 6),),
], 'structA struct<a:int, b:int, c:int>')
df.show()
df.printSchema()

+---------+
|  structA|
+---------+
|{1, 2, 3}|
|{4, 5, 6}|
+---------+

root
 |-- structA: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- a: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |-- b: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |-- c: integer (nullable = true)
```

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

struct_col = 'structA'
struct_cols = [[F.col(b.name).alias(f'{a.name}_{b.name}') for b in a.dataType.fields] for a in df.schema if a.name == struct_col][0]
# [Column<'a AS structA_a'>, Column<'b AS structA_b'>, Column<'c AS structA_c'>]

df.select(f'{struct_col}.*').select(struct_cols).show()
+---------+---------+---------+
|structA_a|structA_b|structA_c|
+---------+---------+---------+
|        1|        2|        3|
|        4|        5|        6|
+---------+---------+---------+
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer, could o please add the part where you initialize the df variable?

Just to be easier to recreate on my side

Comment: Yes I updated my answer

Comment: I accepted your answer because technically it answers my question :)
Thank you for that.

But I like my answer better because I didn't understand so well the final part of struct_cols

but still is a great answer, and the way you created the initial data frame is very cool I will start to create them that way.  Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I did the following in order to do this:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType,StructField, StringType, IntegerType
#create dataframe ----
df_data=[((1,2,3),(-1,-2,-3)),((4,5,6),(-4,-5,-6))]
structureSchema = StructType([
        StructField('structA', StructType([
             StructField('a', IntegerType(), True),
             StructField('b', IntegerType(), True),
             StructField('c', IntegerType(), True)
             ])),
         StructField('structB', StructType([
             StructField('a', IntegerType(), True),
             StructField('b', IntegerType(), True),
             StructField('c', IntegerType(), True)
             ]))
         ])
df=spark.createDataFrame(df_data,structureSchema)
df.show()
+---------+------------+
|  structA|     structB|
+---------+------------+
|[1, 2, 3]|[-1, -2, -3]|
|[4, 5, 6]|[-4, -5, -6]|
+---------+------------+
```

If we have multiple struct like columns we need to find them like this:

```
nested_cols = [c[0] for c in df.dtypes if c[1][:6] == 'struct']
nested_cols

['structA', 'structB']
```

Now I will create a json like object with the new structure

```
struct_columns={}
for struct_column in nested_cols:
  struct_columns[struct_column]=df.select(struct_column+".*").columns
  
struct_columns

{'structA': ['a', 'b', 'c'], 'structB': ['a', 'b', 'c']}
```

With the structure, I will create the flattened data frame

```
flatten_df=df
for key in struct_columns:
  print(key)
  for column in struct_columns[key]:
    flatten_df=flatten_df.withColumn(key+"_"+column,F.expr(f"{key}.{column}"))

flatten_df.drop(*df.columns).show()
+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|structA_a|structA_b|structA_c|structB_a|structB_b|structB_c|
+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|        1|        2|        3|       -1|       -2|       -3|
|        4|        5|        6|       -4|       -5|       -6|
+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
```